# Hardness of maximizing $x^TAy$ with $\{-1,1\}$ entries

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, np-hardness, co.combinatorics, optimization

My question concerns the NP-hardness of the following discrete optimization problem:

Given a matrix $A \in \{ \pm 1 \}^{m\times n}$,

$$\begin{array}{ll} \underset{x \in \{ \pm 1 \}^m ,\, y \in \{ \pm 1 \}^n}{\text{maximize}} & x^T A \, y\end{array}$$

Is this problem known to be NP-hard?

Comment: If $A$ can also have zero entries, then it is NP-hard. I doubt this is really necessary, but I don't have an immediate argument for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

NP-hardness is proved by Roth and Viswanathan in the paper [On the hardness of decoding the gale-berlekamp code](https://doi.org/10.1109/TIT.2007.915716)

Comment: Thank you very much! I also found a proof in https://doi.org/10.1287/moor.2017.0895.

Comment: Yes - They appear to have rediscovered the proof of Roth and Viswanathan.